# Naming a Cell in Numbers

Tags: numbers, macos, terminology

Can you define a cell's name in Numbers for use in formulas across a workbook like you can in Excel?

Comment: Have a look at: [Refer to cells in formulas](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/8.1/#/ffa550d691)

Answer (score 1):

Numbers has some limitations when compared with Excel.

You can't reference sheets in a different Numbers file, for example.

The best you can do is to reference a cell withing the same file but on a different worksheet.  This works the same in Numbers as it does in Excel.

You can request this feature by using the [Numbers Feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html).